# Send data do Cloud (IotHub)

Tags: c#, uwp, iot, azure-iot-hub

I need to send this data below to the cloud, I've tried to mix it with a code in IoT Hub called `SimulatedDevice`, but I Always have some errors.

```
if (reading.IsValid)
{
    this.TotalSuccess++;
    this.Temperature = Convert.ToSingle(reading.Temperature);
    this.Humidity = Convert.ToSingle(reading.Humidity);
    this.LastUpdated = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SuccessRate));

    //  this.WriteData(); 
}
```

To do that, I've to mix the code above with this code here: [IoT-hub C#: get started from azure.microsoft.com](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/).

In my case I've to send temperature an humidity, someone could help? To send this information to the cloud? How could I mix these both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you're running your app on windows IoT devices(like raspberry pi), so you need to develop UWP app, the reference you provide is for console app, which does not run on windows IoT devices.

There's an nice VS extension called **Connected Service for Azure IoT Hub**, as below,
[image]

After you install it, you can "connect to Azure IoT" Hub in the "Add Connected Service" pop up, all the necessary references will be automatically added, and an AzureIoTHub.cs file is created too.

Note you'll need to add **"Windows IoT Extension for the UWP"** extension to you project otherwise you'll run into error.

After you are done, you can update the data to your Azure IoT Hub. I have verified it on my raspberry pi 2 with IoT Core 14393.

Alternatively, there's an [UWP sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/samples/UWPSample) app from azure-iot-sdk github repo, note that you'll need to reference "Windows.Azure.Devices.Client" instead of "Windows.Azure.Devices.Client.WinRT". It also works with my rapberry pi 2.